# Client hostname attribute in radius request

Tags: radius, freeradius, accounting

I am now trying to run logging of accounting information into my database. I use FreeRadius. I have read at glance a few RFC for radius accounting and authentication, so I expect that it is not possible, but I want to ask. Is there any attribute for user's hostname? And if it is not, why?

*-- 26. 2. update*

Sorry for short info. I want to collect data about successful and unsuccessful login attempts to various devices/services inside our company network. In the future, login attempts will not be logged only from the radius server, but so far I am only testing wifi network with enterprise login via FreeRadius. When I log data from radius, I use accounting for successful attempts and authentication for rejected access. We also have a VPN server that only supports radius authentication, so for services without accounting support, all logging will be done by the authentication part. I prepared a simple database scheme and found the most interesting attributes from authentication and accounting and chose these: User-Name, Framed-IP-Address, Calling-Station-Id and NAS-IP-Address. For good overview, it would be nice to also have hostname of user device, but such an attribute is missing (I know that it may be sent some vendor-specific attributes, but they differ from various vendors, so I do not want to use them). When I have user's MAC address from Calling-Station-Id or IP address from Framed-IP-Address, I can look at DHCP leases, but getting the hostname from another database is more uncomfortable for me. So I am just curios why the hostname attribute is not part of radius protocol (I tried dumping accounting traffic, but I found just values which I expected).

Comment: You've provided very little detail of your specific use case to make much of an informed recommendation.  For some generic advice, try taking a packet capture of your udp port 1813 traffic and look thru the AVPs present.  You might be surprised at what you find (pay particular attention to IP addresses - don't look for just hostnames) given the many applications for RADIUS.  (I deal with RADIUS/DIAMETER all day long at a large telecom)

Comment: Getting the hostname of the device would requre the system to use DNS, which it may not need otherwise. If you have the IP you can easliy discover the hostname, in multiple different ways.